# How to tell NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert to serialize an enum to a string and not an int

Tags: c#, json

I currently have a class say (that looks like this)

```
public class foo
{
    public MyEnumType Result { get; set; };
}
```

currently when I do this

```
foo a = new foo();
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
```

The Result comes out as int type. Is there a way for me to get it as string type ? by telling it to do MyEnumTypeInstance.toString();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.Net has a built-in converter, the [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm), you just add an attribute to the property you are [de]serialising, for example:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public MyEnumType Result { get; set; }
```

Or specify the converter during serialisation:

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, new StringEnumConverter());
```